# How to style a webform like a spreadsheet?

Tags: 6, webforms

I've been asked to develop a webform to look like a spreadsheet.
Unfortunately, the site is written in D6 and I've only really developed in D7.

Can anyone recommend a module / method to achieve this?

Comment: Kiamlaluno - I appreciate that this may be classified as off-topic, sorry about that.  But this place is also an awesome tool to stand on the shoulders of giants (or other drupal developers)
Is there a particular area or forum out there that you can recommend I use in future ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for [Webform Table Element](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_table_element) that will render your webform inside a table.

> This module will add a new component to Webform module that allows you
>   to render multiple components inside a table element.